# how to show liste filtre admin django ManyToOne

Tags: python, django, many-to-one

how to show liste filtre admin django  ManyToOne in this case :

in models.py -----------

class Personne(models.Model):

```
name= models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)

def __str__(self):
    return  self.name
```

class Project(models.Model):

```
title= models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
note= models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)

def __str__(self):
    return  self.title
```

class Task(models.Model):

```
title= models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
projecttasktask= models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
personnetask= models.ForeignKey(Personne, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return  self.title
```

in admin.py ---------------

ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
list_filter = ()
```

How can i filtre in Project by tasks and specialy by Personne

liste dropdown of personne and show me liste of projects ?

best ragards

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `ForeignKey` fields to `list_filter`

```
class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_filter = ['projecttasktask', 'personnetask']
```

Comment: but this if i want to show it in Task admin , but i want the filtre in ProjectAdmin

Comment: Then you need to create a custom list filter , https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/filters/#using-a-simplelistfilter